# What is the advantage of a Restful WebService other than interoperability?

Tags: rest, web-services, spring-mvc

I am new to web services in general. But, I am unable to understand it's real advantage over traditional MVC architecture.

I know the fact that if I expose a web service, other applications written in other programming language can understand (As the data will be exchanged in XML or JSON)

But what if there is no need for my application to communicate with other application? Do i still have a reason to use Web Services?

As per my understanding. In traditional MVC app, when browser sends a request, the server will respond back with HTML. With web services, only data will be sent and client code like Angular JS will render that data on browser with styling. But, still. What should I still use rest api? The same result can be accomplished with traditional MVC too..

Comment: I put some effort and time to answer your question, so I appreciate any feedback in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57672010/1426227).

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Fielding's dissertation, where the REST architectural style is defined along with some constraints.

So let me highlight a few of these constraints and the problems they aim to solve:

- **Client-server:** Enforce the separation of concerns and improve scalability by simplifying the server components. It allows the client and the server to evolve individually.
- **Stateless:** Each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to be understood by the server, without taking advantage of any stored context on the server, allowing scalabity.
- **Cache:** Encourages the storage of cacheable data to improve the network efficiency.
- **Uniform Interface:** Aims to simplify the overall system architecture and improve the visibility of the interactions. It builds on the top of other 4 constraints:

  - Identification of resources;
  - Manipulation of resources through representations;
  - Self-descriptive messages;
  - Hypermedia as the engine of application state.
- **Layered System**: Allows an architecture to be composed of hierarchical layers by constraining component behavior such that each component cannot "see" beyond the immediate layer with which they are interacting. It helps create a more scalable and modular application.

It's also important to highlight that the central piece of REST is the **resource**. And a resource can have *multiple representations*. The goal behind supporting multiple representations for the same resource is that the client would be able to choose the representation that best suit their needs. It's called **content negotiation** and it's encouraged in the REST architectural style.